# How to change Primefaces Datatable filter position?

Tags: primefaces

Right now by default PF Datatable showing filter position with header .Is it possible to show filter position on footer of the DataTable ?

I tried below code in Datatble Footer but not worked

```
<f:facet name="footer">
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="filter">
                <p:spinner onchange="PF('carsTable').filter()" styleClass="year-spinner">
                    <f:converter converterId="javax.faces.Integer" />
                </p:spinner>
            </f:facet>
        </p:column>

        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="filter">
                <p:spinner onchange="PF('carsTable').filter()" styleClass="year-spinner">
                    <f:converter converterId="javax.faces.Integer" />
                </p:spinner>
            </f:facet>
        </p:column>
</f:facet>
```

Comment: Might be possible using OmniFaces' `moveComponent` http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/moveComponent

Comment: @MathieuCastets Thanks Will check dont know how it will work.

Answer (score 0):

No, not possible in this way. I see three options:

1. Use DOM manipulation to move the filters to the corresponding tags in the bottom. Do not forget to do this after each ajax call. And by hiding the filters in the header with css anyway, you prevent a 'jumpy' userinterface
2. Using OmniFaces' moveComponent showcase.omnifaces.org/components/moveComponent as proposed by @MathieuCastets
3. Change the source of the PrimeFaces dataTable and create your own component.

Comment: I am trying something else see if i get sucess

Comment: If that is the omnifaces moveComponent, that might work. It is under the hood doing  some clever things. I forgot that option.